# Run a Hash Checking code as a job powershell

Tags: powershell, file, hash, export-to-csv, jobs

I looked into some of the posts here but didn't found an answer to my situation, I have the following script in which I parse through multiple servers checking the hash code of certain files, I use foreach to do this trick and wished to pass each server as a job that runs the foreach loop, otherwise it takes an awfully long time to do.

Here's the code:

```
$Modulos = Get-Content -Path .\mod.txt |sort-object -unique

$Orig = "H:\Redsys_Client"
$Machines = Get-Content -Path .\servers.txt |sort-object -unique



function CheckFileHash ($file, $file2 ,$cLogFile) {

$hashSrc = Get-FileHash $file -Algorithm "SHA256"
$hashDest = Get-FileHash $file2 -Algorithm "SHA256"
if ((test-path -Path $cLogFile ) -eq $False){
Add-Content -Path $cLogFile -Value "Algor; Hash_Orig; Orig; Algor; Hash_Dest; Dest; Result"
}

If ($hashSrc.Hash -ne $hashDest.Hash)
{
  Add-Content -Path $cLogFile -Value "$hashSrc; $hashDest; the files are NOT EQUAL."
}
elseif ($hashSrc.Hash -eq $hashDest.Hash){
Add-Content -Path $cLogFile -Value "$hashSrc; $hashDest; the files are EQUAL."
}

}


Foreach ($Server in $Machines){
  Foreach ($name in $Modulos){
  CheckFileHash $orig\$name\$name.exe "\\$Server\Redsys\$name\$name.exe" ".\test.csv"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this kind of job ? I'm afraid that it'd just mess a lot with the csv and wished to try to store them on a variable, dunno

Comment: If you have the ability to `Invoke-Command` it would be a lot faster than using `Start-Job`. Honestly a linear loop as you're doing would be as fast as `Start-Job`.

Comment: didn't know that, how'd you apply invoke command in here?:

Comment: Test this line to see if there is no restriction: `Invoke-Command $Machines -ScriptBlock { $env:COMPUTERNAME }` if that runs property it should return an array of all the computer names on your `$Machines` variable. Make sure to load the variable before running that => `$Machines = Get-Content -Path .\servers.txt`

Comment: As you are writing a CSV you might also want to consider using a hashtable to generate your output in combination with Export-Csv or ConvertTo-Csv.

Comment: if you run PowerShell 7, you can try use foreach-object -parallel it will require least changes to your existing script. Example : https://mohitgoyal.co/2021/04/15/parallel-execution-with-foreach-in-powershell/

Comment: @Seth don't know how to do a hashtable but gonna look into it, seems way less unstable than rn, gonna test the invoke-command and -parallel on powershell 7, gonna answer what I find here later, Thank you guys!